# mySQL problem how to know the number of each color

Tags: php, mysql

I have database with images on it

example:

i have 5 of clothes images
and  from this 6 there are two images with blue color, 3 images with pink and the last one with green color.

and i have a search input ,
i want tell the user when he search for clothes the number of each color.
i want the output like this :
blue(2) - pink(3) - green(1)

i know how to figure out the number of the word that he searched for it,

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE classification='$request'");

$num = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

but what i want is how to know the number of each color for the word that he searched for it.

Comment: Needs more info, like your table structure

Comment: I take it you store the colour in the table?

Comment: I stored my images and there main color in database.id(1)-clclassification(clothes)-color(red)-URL(images/example.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing from the query you provided, try a query like this:

```
SELECT color, COUNT(*) AS total FROM images WHERE classification='$request' GROUP BY color
```

Comment: I don't understand ok now i know that there is a count function
how can i display the result ?
also i want this with WHERE
so when the user search for clothes
he count just the classification 'clothes'
and when he searched for shoes he just cont the color of shoes.
thank you

Comment: Please see the updated query. Please also remember to sanitize $request to prevent SQL injection attacks.